Data with utf8_unicode_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_ci dispaly error in text via php
Old Server - with mysql 5.7.33 and data / article content was saved in utf8_unicode_ci as it contains Devnagari / Hindi Font content
Data saved in db, database structure with collation and ourput is shown serially in below images.
Now Moved website to
New Server - mysql 8.0.31
Uploaded database from old server phpmyadmin backuped sql file.
utf8_unicode_ci collation is now autochanged to utf8mb3_unicode_ci. So I changed it to utf8mb4_unicode_ci
Now in next images, I am showing Data saved in db, database structure with collation and output.
My article text display as devnagari / hindi is lost on new server with mysql 8.0.31
I tried
- header in php with utf-8
- using font-face (both on old sever and now on new server too with same font family for hindi / devnagari font).
- set_charset("utf8") and/or set_charset("utf8mb4") after db connection
- adding meta tag with text/html utf8 in head section of page

But nothing is working......
Images serially for OLD Server and NEW server
Server using and image number given in image
Image 1 :

Image 2 :

Image 3 :

NOW NEW SERVER :
Image 4 :

Image 5 :

Image 6 :


Obviously, these texts are not originally encoded using UTF-8. They should have been encoded using your country's ANSI/OEM code page and saved to the database as binary, so there is no need to change the collation.

@shingo collation getting autochanged when uploading to new server phpmyadmin as it is with mysql 8.0.31 newer version where utf_8_unicode_ci is depreciated hence removed. and with utf8mb4 collation, display text is messed up.. as shown in last image

It is not and it won't be removed: utf8 is expected in a future release to become an alias for utf8mb4

@shingo Ok... But now when I moved files as it is from old server to new server and uploaded database downloaded from old server to new server without changing anything..., on old server text is showing properly and on new server not displaying properly... what can be causes ?

Canonical reference: UTF-8 all the way through . But as shingo says, that may not help you much if the data was never utf8 to begin with.

@DrMLMJ, need debugging infomation, you can start by fetching one same text from both server, then convert them with bin2hex. If they are the same, the problem should be in the php code. If not the problem should be in the mysql config.

@shingoI checked bin2hex from both servers. Output of bin2hex are same. What php settings will be needed to display text properly ?

@DrMLMJ, check 1. The content type in the http response header. 2. The page source, especially the meta charset tag in the html header and the corrupted text in the body. See which data is different from the old website.

This question is pretty much the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78387152/losing-devnagari-text-display-when-migrating-from-utf8-to-utf8mb4

See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored
